# what happened when our self function pass as a parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am just ask what happened when our self function pass as a parameter in JavaScript, the value of a pass by call function.

JavaScript:

```
function main(a, b = main()) {
  console.log(a, b);
}
main(4);
```

Comment: This results in an infinite loop? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

> *"VM44:1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"*

You get an error from the call stack size exceeding the maximum, due to recursion.

This is *trivial* to test yourself, by the way; Just copy the code into your developer console and run it.